# Points paid on purchace of principal residence shows up twice

Tags: united-states, income-tax, mortgage, tax-deduction

I received two 1098 tax forms this year because I got a mortgage from one lender and then after a few weeks they sold the debt to another lender.

Both forms show that there are "points paid" on the mortgage (which are tax deductible) and the points paid are exactly the same amount.

Should I report both on my taxes as deductibles or are the "points paid" a duplicate of each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know it is incorrect, then just report one.  It sounds like an obvious mix up on their part.  If you report two, and you get audited, it will cause you more headaches than it is worth.  Being honest goes a long way with the IRS.

Comment: I'm not certain that it's incorrect, since this is the first I've ever heard of "points paid", but I'm assuming that it is since the amounts are the same on both.  Thanks for the advice.  I'm planning on just reporting one of them as you recommend.

Comment: Give the mortgage company a call and advise them of the situation - I am sure you are not going to be the only person who calls them..

Comment: @Jordan points paid are you spending money up front in order to lock in a smaller rate. Effectively, you are pre-paying interest at the beginning of the loan rather than over the lifetime of the loan. Hence, it is usually able to be counted as deductible interest should you choose or be able to itemize your deductions.

Comment: @R.Hamilton, it's just the appearance of two "points paid" for an identical amount after my loan was sold to another company that makes me assume that I shouldn't count it twice.  I did not refi, the sale of my debt was just between the two mortgage companies (as is common)

Answer (score 2):

It seems unlikely that you paid additional points when the mortgage was sold, I've never heard of someone doing that, and I think you would know if you had.

So either this duplicate reporting of points is a mistake, or the second 1098 includes all the amounts you paid, and essentially supersedes the first 1098. It's been a while since I had a mortgage that was sold so I really don't recall if I got two 1098s or one and if two, if the amount on the second was the totals or if I had to add the two together. If there's someone on here who's a banker or otherwise knows how this works, please chime in.

In any case, I'd call the lender and ask. If the points on the second 1098 include the amounts paid to the original lender, then maybe interest payments and other numbers do too.